# What aspects of voting in the USA are left to the states and what are controlled by the federal government?

Tags: united-states, voting

As far as I understand it, the implementation of voting is left up to the individual states in the USA.  On the other hand, federal legislation and rulings by the Supreme Court have certainly affected how votes are conducted.

What aspects of voting are left entirely up to the states?  What aspects of voting is the federal government allowed to control?

Comment: Are you asking about absolute/constitutional limits on federal control of elections, or about current law, that is parts that the federal government could control if they passed a law to do so, but have not so far?

Comment: The absolute limits would probably be an answerable question.  Asking about possible laws would be too broad.

Comment: I was thinking of Asking "Do Americans have the right to vote?".  (This is included in the constitution of many countries).

Comment: FWIW, it is actually a quite complicated division and there are some gray areas.

Answer (score 6):

Let's start with the Constitution Article 1, Section 4, Clause 1

> The Times, Places and Manner of holding Elections for Senators and Representatives, shall be prescribed in each State by the Legislature thereof; but the Congress may at any time by Law make or alter such Regulations, except as to the Places of chusing Senators.

Congress has a [pretty good page on this](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/essay/artI_S4_C1_1_1_1_2/)

> To accomplish the ends under this clause, Congress may adopt the statutes of the states and enforce them by its own sanctions. It may punish a state election officer for violating his duty under a state law governing congressional elections. It may, in short, use its power under this clause, combined with the Necessary and Proper Clause, to regulate the times, places, and manner of electing Members of Congress so as to fully safeguard the integrity of the process; it may not, however, under this clause, provide different qualifications for electors than those provided by the states.

Under [US v Classic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_v._Classic), Congress can regulate primaries as well.

It's unclear where that line stops, though. Courts haven't restricted the Federal government from doing too many things. Generally states can still

1. Draw their own district lines
2. Set times for primary elections
3. Establish the rules for voting (subject to the [Voting Rights Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voting_Rights_Act_of_1965)). This includes rules like registration, days to vote, places to vote, etc.

Comment: Just to clarify, since I’m not sure of this: those 3 things are up to states because Congress hasn’t chosen to regulate them, right?

Comment: I was hoping that an answer **might** enumerate those aspects of the voting process that "are left entirely up to the states"? Are there any?  (one might argue that districting is not a voting process, and that primaries are a creature of political parties to block otherwise qualified candidates --- maybe we need a clearer definition of "voting process"

Comment: @BobE The catch on this is the TL;DR could be written as "The states can do as they see fit, except when Congress says otherwise". So no state can make it illegal for blacks to vote (per the Voting Rights Act). But states can set days and times for voting (before the Federal deadlines)

Comment: The scope of Presidential election regulations is somewhat different, and there are also multiple constitutional amendments with enforcement clauses related to elections as well. So, while this is a good starting point, it isn't comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer already quoted the relevant passage in the Constitution which tells us that in principle, federal congressional elections **could** be regulated almost entirely by the federal government if it chose to do so. It hasn't chosen to do so, many things are still left up to the states.

That applies to federal congressional elections, not state elections or presidential elections, where there are other relevant constitutional provisions. For presidential elections, mainly this is a federal power:

> The Congress may determine the Time of chusing the Electors, and the Day on which they shall give their Votes; which Day shall be the same throughout the United States.

For state elections, my understanding is that federal power derives mainly from the various amendments establishing voting rights (15th, 19th, 24th, 26th); they all contain clauses that say Congress can enforce them by appropriate legislation.

The great thing about the US is that its federal statutes are organized in one document called the [United States Code](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text). We can look at its table of contents and see that [Title 52](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/52) deals exclusively with "Voting and Elections". If you browse through that, you can find some of the aspects of elections that are regulated by federal law.

Other federal regulations of elections can be found under [Title 2 Chapter 1](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/2/chapter-1) ("Election of Senators and Representatives") and [Title 3 Chapter 1](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/3/chapter-1) ("Presidential Elections and Vacancies"). I am not sure whether I missed any other important chapter dealing with federal elections; please leave a comment if I did.

Everything that there is no federal statute about is left to the states.